# Display Model Data in View

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I am having trouble updating the model data and then displaying it my view.

I currently have a MortgageCalculator class that I am using as a model.

```
    public double loan_amount { get; set; }
    public double interest { get; set; }
    public int loan_duration { get; set; }
    public int payments_year { get; set; }
```

Code for the controller is:

```
    [httpGet]
    public ActionResult M_Calculator()
    {
        var mortgageCalculator = new MortgageCalculator();
        return View(mortgageCalculator);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult M_Calculator(MortgageCalculator mortgageCalculator)
    {    
        UpdateModel(mortgageCalculator);
        return RedirectToAction("Results");
    }

    public ActionResult Results (MortgageCalculator mortgageCalculator) 
    {
        return View(mortgageCalculator);
    }
```

Code for my view is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<fieldset>
    <legend>Mortgage Calculator</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.loan_amount)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.loan_amount)
    </div>
    <br />

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.interest)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.interest)
    </div>
    <br />

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.loan_duration)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.loan_duration)
    </div>
    <br />

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.payments_year)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.payments_year)
    </div>
    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" />

</fieldset>
```

}

I want to make some calculations on the data that I receive from the user and then show the results in my Results view. I don't have any database. I just want to perform simple calculations on data and show the results. The solution seems to be pretty straight forward but I am stuck. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Your `Results()` method has a parameter `MortgageCalculator mortgageCalculator` but you not passing anything to that method when you redirect to it, so it will be a default instance. You need to persist the data somewhere in your `M_Calculator` method and then get it again in the `Results()` method. Ideally to a database, but you could use `Session` (including `TempData`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of redirect user to another action you should return your model with the result populated, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult M_Calculator(MortgageCalculator mortgageCalculator)
{    
     UpdateModel(mortgageCalculator);
     return View("Results", mortgageCalculator);
}
```

If you don't want to create another view only to show the results, just remove the first parameter that indicates which view ASP.NET MVC should use, so, it will use the default view.